# Covariation betwee two random variables in terms of covariations between third random variable.

Tags: probability-theory

Let $\xi_1, \xi_2, \xi_3$ be random variables. Is there formula for $cov(\xi_1, \xi_3)$ in terms of $cov(\xi_1, \xi_2)$ and $cov(\xi_2, \xi_3)$?

If there is no direct dependency between $cov(\xi_1, \xi_3)$ and $cov(\xi_1, \xi_2)$, $cov(\xi_2, \xi_3)$, then what would be an example that shows that with given $cov(\xi_1, \xi_2)$, $cov(\xi_2, \xi_3)$, there could be different values of  $cov(\xi_1, \xi_3)$.

Comment: The _average_ of the three _correlations_ must be at least $-\frac{1}{2}$.  See, for example, [_this answer_](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/72795/6633) on stats.SE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct dependency. Let $X,Y,Z$ be i.i.d standard normals. Then letting $\xi_1 = X+Y, \xi_2 = Y+Z, \xi_3 = X+Z$ we have $\rm{Cov}(\xi_1, \xi_2) = \rm{Cov}(\xi_2, \xi_3) = \rm{Cov}(\xi_1, \xi_3) = 1$. Letting $\xi_1 = X+Y, \xi_2 = Y+Z, \xi_3 = Z$ we have $\rm{Cov}(\xi_1, \xi_2) = \rm{Cov}(\xi_2, \xi_3) = 1$ as before but $ \rm{Cov}(\xi_1, \xi_3) = 0$.